# Using a sequence in IN()

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all values which have a certain source value using 
code similar to the following.

```
l.sub IN('12480','12481')
```

However, I need to everything where sub contains the value 10921-12480.
Is there a way to quickly select those values without typing each one out.

Thank You!

Comment: l.sub >= 10921 and l.sub <= 12480?

Comment: Make sure you don't send very long queries, because there's a limit to how long the query can be. Also, the performance of very long queries will drop, since they need to be parsed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `l.sub` is of a numeric type, then you can use `BETWEEN`.

```
l.sub BETWEEN 10921 AND 12480
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to what @Radu said, the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) says that the behavior at the edges of the range is less-than-or-equal-to and greater-than-or-equal-to.

In other words,

```
expr BETWEEN min AND max
```

is the same as

```
(min <= expr AND expr <= max)
```

It also says to check that the types are the same, otherwise you open the type-conversion can of worms!

Answer (score 2):

don't use IN ;)

```
l.sub >= 10921 AND l.sub <= 12480
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that l.sub is a string, you could try the following:

```
length(l.sub) = 5 AND l.sub >= '10921' and l.sub <= '12481'
```